# Base class fields offset

Tags: c++

I have some code that implements a kind of run-time reflection. In order to get a pointer to a field of a class inside a given instance, i basically take the pointer to the class instance and add a fixed offset that is calculated once for each field that is exposed to the reflection library.

I kept the implementation quite simple, since i didn't need to support multiple inheritance and i made the mistake of not taking into account that, even with single inheritance, this situation is possible:

```
class A
{
public:
    unsigned int m_uiField;
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void VirtualMethod()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    unsigned int uiOffsetA(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(&(reinterpret_cast<A *>(0)->m_uiField)));
    // uiOffsetA is 0 on VC9
    unsigned int uiOffsetB(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(&(reinterpret_cast<B *>(0)->m_uiField)));
    // uiOffsetB is 4 on VC9
}
```

In this case the virtual table pointer that my compiler puts at the beginning of each instance of B was offsetting by 4 bytes the fields of A.

My first idea was to do something similar to what i'm doing for the field offsets and store a single unsigned int as an offset for the base class to add to pointers to derived class instances together with the field offset. So, at initialization time i call this function one for each Derived class inheriting from a Base class:

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
unsigned int GetBaseClassOffset()
{
    Derived *pDerived(reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(4));
    Base *pBase(pDerived);
    assert(pBase >= pDerived);
    return reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(pBase) - reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(pDerived);
}
```

And everything seems to work with my tests using VC9.
But then it came to my mind that this area of C++ could be implementation dependent, and that other things like alignment could break this up.

In the end my question is:
Can i assume that fields of a base class will always be positioned at a constant positive offset relative to a pointer to a derived class instance?

Note: i am not saying "constant across all compilers", i will use some code (eventually compiler dependent) to detect this offset at startup.

Comment: [offsetof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/offsetof/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't assume any such thing. The implementation of inheritance (especially polymorphic, multiple and virtual inheritance) is entirely up to the compiler. I think the only thing you can just about assume is that the member objects are ordered in their order of declaration, and they're aligned appropriately.

Comment: @sehe: "POD types only".

Comment: Valerio, note that pointers are 4 bytes on 32 bit OS. On 64 bit, pointers are 8 bytes.

Comment: I've seen many attempts at reflection in C++, and they have all been really nasty hacks. Just use `operator <<` and `operator >>` within a chunk based stream (like .png) where the chunk header is the class type accessed through a virtual `GetClassType` or something.

Comment: @valerio: for pure C-style structs, you could run your headers through the ancient **[`pstruct`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pstruct.htm)** utility

Comment: My question was confusing, and seems to have brought up some kind of debate on whether reflection in c++ is possible or not in general, so i'll assign this one and open another one where i focus on the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this situation, you can use pointer-to-members:

See it live: http://ideone.com/U4w7j

```
struct A
{
    unsigned int m_uiField;
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual void VirtualMethod() { }
};

int main()
{
    A instance_a;
    B instance_b;

    unsigned int A::*  ptrA = &A::m_uiField;
    unsigned int B::*  ptrB = &B::m_uiField;

    // application:
    unsigned int value = instance_a.*ptrA;
                 value = instance_b.*ptrA;
               //value = instance_a.*ptrB; // incompatible types
                 value = instance_b.*ptrB;

    // also:
    A* dynamic = new B();
    value = dynamic->*ptrA; // etc
}
```

I suggest you also look at template metaprogramming features (part of TR1 and C++11 now:), notably the `is_pod` type trait:

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/header_type_traits.htm
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/structstd_1_1tr1_1_1is__pod.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982918(v=VS.100).aspx

This is important because using offsetof on anything else is hazardous.

Comment: Those are not MPL features if you are talking about Boost.MPL, or are you referring to general metaprogramming? They are part of the Boost.TypeTraits library.

Comment: K-ballo: you explained it yourself. General metaprogramming. I think I remember it being introduced as such in ["The C++ Library and Extensions"](http://www.amazon.com/Standard-Library-Extensions-Tutorial-Reference/dp/0321412990) - unfortunately the books index is exceptionally poor (there isn't an entry for `is_pod` nor is there one, indeed, for `template` ... :))

Comment: The reason why i didn't use field pointers since the beginning is that they can't be casted to unsigned int and then used as i do with offsets. In order to get a pointer to the field with a field pointer i need a virtual function or a function pointer to some template function that knows how to use it.

Comment: @valerio: so basically, you're saying, that you prefer being able to cause undefined behaviour? If you need a pointer to a specific instance member, you can have it. If you need a 'generic' pointer to the 'member inside _any_ instance of a type', you _should_ use pointer to member or you're going to end up belly-up.

Comment: I don't prefer undefined behaviour, I just want to make sure that precalculating constant offsets is not an option, because it would be faster and takes less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Standard-conformant implementation of reflection in C++ (including C++11) is not possible. Mainly because member offset is not standardized and so depends of compiler. It depends on polimorphism implementation, on alignment and probably on other things.

You can implement reflection for specific compiler, or for limited range of classes.

[Much more info about C++ reflection is here](http://www.garret.ru/cppreflection/docs/reflect.html).

Reflection support was proposed for C++11 standard but was postponed because required much more time.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i assume that fields of a base class will always be positioned at a constant positive offset relative to a pointer to a derived class instance?

No, you can't. Why is that a possitive offset? I would expect that in common implementations base members are placed **before** the derived classes?

Note the standard 'operator' (well not quite) `offsetof`, which will give you the offset from a struct to a member. It's usually implemented as a macro similar to yours, derreferencing the null pointer. It probably won't help you since its guaranteed to work only with POD type classes. See 18.2/4 at the standard:

> The macro offsetof(type, member-designator) accepts a restricted set of type arguments in this International
>   Standard. If type is not a standard-layout class (Clause 9), the results are undeﬁned.

Comment: Positive meaning that they are at or after the byte referred to the pointer to the derived class instance, and not before.